# How to get all my keys to send keycodes

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using Gentoo with XFCE.  I have a logitech K350 keyboard, all but a few of the keys work as expected but there is one specific key that I want to use but when I run `showkey` no key codes are being sent.  The key is the arrange windows button on the bottom left of the keyboard.

[image].

Is this a driver issue and is it possible to get that key to send a code so that I can map an action to it?

Comment: While running `xev` does that produce any output when you press the key? Also take a look at my previous answers that make use of `xev`. They should get you started: http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A7453+xev

Comment: @slm there is no output from xev associated with the keypress.

Comment: This post might be helpful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work

Comment: I'm trying to follow the guide here https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2012/logitech-k750-linux-support to be able to finds out what signals are being sent.  I think that there are certain keys that must be passed not with key press codes but with some other type of usb signal that is not handled by the hid-logitech-dj driver.

Comment: With USB keyboards you can use the command `xinput` to get additional info from them.

Comment: Found this guide that shows how to get that keyboard working under linux: http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~klada/?site=projects&id=logitechkbd. If this one works please write it up. I don't have this keyboard so you're likely going to be the best candidate to write up your own answer 8-)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that even on Windows 10, that key does not generate a scancode unless you are running the proprietary Logitech Setpoint driver.  It sucks, I know.

Answer (score 19):

Don't use `showkey` or `xev` -- use `udev` and `evtest` instead.

Look at the output of `evtest`

```
# evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:      Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard
/dev/input/event1:      Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard
/dev/input/event2:      Power Button
/dev/input/event3:      Power Button
/dev/input/event4:      PC Speaker
/dev/input/event5:      A4Tech USB Mouse
/dev/input/event6:      ACPI Virtual Keyboard Device
Select the device event number [0-6]: 0
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x46d product 0xc30f version 0x110
Input device name: "Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    Event code 2 (KEY_1)
    Event code 3 (KEY_2)
    Event code 4 (KEY_3)
    Event code 5 (KEY_4)
    Event code 6 (KEY_5)
    Event code 7 (KEY_6)
    Event code 8 (KEY_7)
    Event code 9 (KEY_8)
    Event code 10 (KEY_9)
    Event code 11 (KEY_0)
    Event code 12 (KEY_MINUS)
    Event code 13 (KEY_EQUAL)
    Event code 14 (KEY_BACKSPACE)
    Event code 15 (KEY_TAB)
    Event code 16 (KEY_Q)
    Event code 17 (KEY_W)
    Event code 18 (KEY_E)
    Event code 19 (KEY_R)
    Event code 20 (KEY_T)
    Event code 21 (KEY_Y)
    Event code 22 (KEY_U)
    Event code 23 (KEY_I)
    Event code 24 (KEY_O)
    Event code 25 (KEY_P)
    Event code 26 (KEY_LEFTBRACE)
    Event code 27 (KEY_RIGHTBRACE)
    Event code 28 (KEY_ENTER)
    Event code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL)
    Event code 30 (KEY_A)
    Event code 31 (KEY_S)
    Event code 32 (KEY_D)
    Event code 33 (KEY_F)
    Event code 34 (KEY_G)
    Event code 35 (KEY_H)
    Event code 36 (KEY_J)
    Event code 37 (KEY_K)
    Event code 38 (KEY_L)
    Event code 39 (KEY_SEMICOLON)
    Event code 40 (KEY_APOSTROPHE)
    Event code 41 (KEY_GRAVE)
    Event code 42 (KEY_LEFTSHIFT)
    Event code 43 (KEY_BACKSLASH)
    Event code 44 (KEY_Z)
    Event code 45 (KEY_X)
    Event code 46 (KEY_C)
    Event code 47 (KEY_V)
    Event code 48 (KEY_B)
    Event code 49 (KEY_N)
    Event code 50 (KEY_M)
    Event code 51 (KEY_COMMA)
    Event code 52 (KEY_DOT)
    Event code 53 (KEY_SLASH)
    Event code 54 (KEY_RIGHTSHIFT)
    Event code 55 (KEY_KPASTERISK)
    Event code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT)
    Event code 57 (KEY_SPACE)
    Event code 58 (KEY_CAPSLOCK)
    Event code 59 (KEY_F1)
    Event code 60 (KEY_F2)
    Event code 61 (KEY_F3)
    Event code 62 (KEY_F4)
    Event code 63 (KEY_F5)
    Event code 64 (KEY_F6)
    Event code 65 (KEY_F7)
    Event code 66 (KEY_F8)
    Event code 67 (KEY_F9)
    Event code 68 (KEY_F10)
    Event code 69 (KEY_NUMLOCK)
    Event code 70 (KEY_SCROLLLOCK)
    Event code 71 (KEY_KP7)
    Event code 72 (KEY_KP8)
    Event code 73 (KEY_KP9)
    Event code 74 (KEY_KPMINUS)
    Event code 75 (KEY_KP4)
    Event code 76 (KEY_KP5)
    Event code 77 (KEY_KP6)
    Event code 78 (KEY_KPPLUS)
    Event code 79 (KEY_KP1)
    Event code 80 (KEY_KP2)
    Event code 81 (KEY_KP3)
    Event code 82 (KEY_KP0)
    Event code 83 (KEY_KPDOT)
    Event code 85 (KEY_ZENKAKUHANKAKU)
    Event code 86 (KEY_102ND)
    Event code 87 (KEY_F11)
    Event code 88 (KEY_F12)
    Event code 89 (KEY_RO)
    Event code 90 (KEY_KATAKANA)
    Event code 91 (KEY_HIRAGANA)
    Event code 92 (KEY_HENKAN)
    Event code 93 (KEY_KATAKANAHIRAGANA)
    Event code 94 (KEY_MUHENKAN)
    Event code 95 (KEY_KPJPCOMMA)
    Event code 96 (KEY_KPENTER)
    Event code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL)
    Event code 98 (KEY_KPSLASH)
    Event code 99 (KEY_SYSRQ)
    Event code 100 (KEY_RIGHTALT)
    Event code 102 (KEY_HOME)
    Event code 103 (KEY_UP)
    Event code 104 (KEY_PAGEUP)
    Event code 105 (KEY_LEFT)
    Event code 106 (KEY_RIGHT)
    Event code 107 (KEY_END)
    Event code 108 (KEY_DOWN)
    Event code 109 (KEY_PAGEDOWN)
    Event code 110 (KEY_INSERT)
    Event code 111 (KEY_DELETE)
    Event code 113 (KEY_MUTE)
    Event code 114 (KEY_VOLUMEDOWN)
    Event code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP)
    Event code 116 (KEY_POWER)
    Event code 117 (KEY_KPEQUAL)
    Event code 119 (KEY_PAUSE)
    Event code 121 (KEY_KPCOMMA)
    Event code 122 (KEY_HANGUEL)
    Event code 123 (KEY_HANJA)
    Event code 124 (KEY_YEN)
    Event code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA)
    Event code 126 (KEY_RIGHTMETA)
    Event code 127 (KEY_COMPOSE)
    Event code 128 (KEY_STOP)
    Event code 129 (KEY_AGAIN)
    Event code 130 (KEY_PROPS)
    Event code 131 (KEY_UNDO)
    Event code 132 (KEY_FRONT)
    Event code 133 (KEY_COPY)
    Event code 134 (KEY_OPEN)
    Event code 135 (KEY_PASTE)
    Event code 136 (KEY_FIND)
    Event code 137 (KEY_CUT)
    Event code 138 (KEY_HELP)
    Event code 183 (KEY_F13)
    Event code 184 (KEY_F14)
    Event code 185 (KEY_F15)
    Event code 186 (KEY_F16)
    Event code 187 (KEY_F17)
    Event code 188 (KEY_F18)
    Event code 189 (KEY_F19)
    Event code 190 (KEY_F20)
    Event code 191 (KEY_F21)
    Event code 192 (KEY_F22)
    Event code 193 (KEY_F23)
    Event code 194 (KEY_F24)
    Event code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
  Event type 17 (EV_LED)
    Event code 0 (LED_NUML)
    Event code 1 (LED_CAPSL)
    Event code 2 (LED_SCROLLL)
    Event code 3 (LED_COMPOSE)
    Event code 4 (LED_KANA)
Properties:
  Property type 20 (EV_REP)
    Property code 0 (REP_DELAY)
      Value    250
    Property code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
      Value     33
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
```

and the second device (the same keyboard, but it has multimedia keys):

```
# evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:      Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard
/dev/input/event1:      Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard
/dev/input/event2:      Power Button
/dev/input/event3:      Power Button
/dev/input/event4:      PC Speaker
/dev/input/event5:      A4Tech USB Mouse
/dev/input/event6:      ACPI Virtual Keyboard Device
Select the device event number [0-6]: 1
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x46d product 0xc30f version 0x110
Input device name: "Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 113 (KEY_MUTE)
    Event code 114 (KEY_VOLUMEDOWN)
    Event code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP)
    Event code 116 (KEY_POWER)
    Event code 131 (KEY_UNDO)
    Event code 138 (KEY_HELP)
    Event code 140 (KEY_CALC)
    Event code 142 (KEY_SLEEP)
    Event code 143 (KEY_WAKEUP)
    Event code 155 (KEY_MAIL)
    Event code 156 (KEY_BOOKMARKS)
    Event code 158 (KEY_BACK)
    Event code 159 (KEY_FORWARD)
    Event code 163 (KEY_NEXTSONG)
    Event code 164 (KEY_PLAYPAUSE)
    Event code 165 (KEY_PREVIOUSSONG)
    Event code 166 (KEY_STOPCD)
    Event code 168 (KEY_REWIND)
    Event code 171 (KEY_CONFIG)
    Event code 172 (KEY_HOMEPAGE)
    Event code 182 (KEY_REDO)
    Event code 208 (KEY_FASTFORWARD)
    Event code 210 (KEY_PRINT)
    Event code 217 (KEY_SEARCH)
    Event code 234 (KEY_SAVE)
    Event code 319 (?)
    Event code 328 (BTN_TOOL_QUINTTAP)
    Event code 329 (?)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
    Event code 331 (BTN_STYLUS)
    Event code 418 (KEY_ZOOMIN)
    Event code 419 (KEY_ZOOMOUT)
    Event code 420 (KEY_ZOOMRESET)
    Event code 421 (KEY_WORDPROCESSOR)
    Event code 423 (KEY_SPREADSHEET)
    Event code 425 (KEY_PRESENTATION)
    Event code 430 (KEY_MESSENGER)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
```

All events that have codes > 255 won't work, and you have to remap the keys. But first you have to get some scan codes:

```
# /lib/udev/keymap -i input/event1
Press ESC to finish, or Control-C if this device is not your primary keyboard
scan code: 0xC022D   key code: zoomin
scan code: 0xC022E   key code: zoomout
```

and press keys that don't work. If you won't get any scancodes here, the key is probably dead, and you can do nothing about it.

Now you have to check what keycodes are free -- you can do it by shooting based on the `/usr/include/linux/input.h` file, let's say:

```
#define KEY_PROG3        202
#define KEY_PROG4       203
```

or you can press each key on your keyboard and map them manually.

Anyway, if you know what keycodes are free, you can create a file with similar content to this one:

```
0xC022D PROG3
0xC022E PROG4
```

You can save it in `/lib/udev/keymaps/logitech-media-keyboard-elite` -- that's for my keyboard.

And now, you have to create a rule for `udev`, it should look like this:

```
KERNEL=="event*", ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="046d", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="c30f", RUN+="/lib/udev/keymap $name /lib/udev/keymaps/logitech-media-keyboard-elite"
```

`ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}`, `ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}` and other parameters you can read from:

```
# udevadm info /dev/input/event0
```

or:

```
# udevadm info --name /dev/input/event0 --attribute-walk
```

Save this rule under `/etc/udev/rules.d/95-keymap-media-keyboard-elite.rules` and replug your keyboard. It works for me well, and it should for you as well.

Comment: evtest does not capture the events for the key that I am concerned about.  There is something that is being lost.  Wireshark sees the events but nothing else appears to be seeing them  I think that this must be a driver issue.  as far as I can tell the hid-logitech-dj driver captures the output and forwards it on to the hid-core.  Somewhere there is is lost.

Comment: Maybe you are using wrong device?

Comment: This appears out of date now, since `/lib/udev/keymap` has apparently been removed. https://askubuntu.com/questions/362373/how-to-remap-key-codes-without-usr-lib-keymap-which-is-gone-in-saucy-and-in/456550#456550

Comment: Yes, the idea I described here is now out of date. Instead, udev uses files that you put in `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/` .

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov absolutely brilliant and detailed answer! Cheers!

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov Knowing that `/lib/udev/keymap` tool has been removed, how do I get the scan codes using `udev` ?