# Does gnome-terminal have an equivalent for xterm's modifyOtherKeys?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal

[xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/) has a [`modifyOtherKeys` option](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#RESOURCES) that tells it to construct an escape sequence for various key combinations that are normally not available. That option can be enabled in `.Xdefaults`, or with a control sequence from within the terminal (`echo -n -e '\033[>4;1m'` does the trick for me).

This option allows for more key combinations to be bound to commands in text mode programs, e.g. in [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). For example `C-'` (`Ctrl + '`) will normally generate a single `'` character, which is useless, but will turn into a complex - but usable - escape sequence when the `modifyOtherKeys` option is enabled.

Does `gnome-terminal` have a similar ability? I could not find anything in the menus on my system (Mageia Linux 4, gnome-terminal-3.10.2), but perhaps there is some control sequence with the same effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but there's an open bug asking for this: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=730157

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to be indeed the answer for now...