# Keyboard key is not recognized even with showkey

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout, key-mapping

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, in a laptop that I carry around and use with different physical keyboards (as I don't feel comfortable with laptop keyboards)

For one of those keyboards (Dell SK-8135) the Super and Menu (?) keys are not recognized:

- xev ignores keypresses completely for those 2 keys
- showkey -s (ran as root, in the console) also ignores keypresses completely

I know that these keys in my keyboard work on other computers (I could not try them in another Linux based computer).  I am 80% sure this particular keyboard used to work ok with an older version of Linux I used to have (it could have been a similar keyboard).

I tried also, with no avail, things of the like

```
setxkbmap  -model dellsk8135
setxkbmap  -model dellsk8135 -print | xkbcomp - $DISPLAY
```

Any debugging clues appreciated; I am not sure how to go below "showkey" command.

Comment: This Q&A explains key presses + keyboard: [How do keyboard input and text output work?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work/116630#116630)

Comment: According to this Q&A, the main suspects would be the motherboard, CPU and kernel.  None of witch I am able to debug. I suppose that I can narrow the suspect list by using a live distro with a different kernel (I am not sure if there are non Linux live distros out there), but I am not sure if that could be useful for solving the problem (since I cannot change kernel nor hardware)

Comment: I would try that, it will give you additional info that may help in determining root cause.

Comment: The Linux kernel is the most likely culprit: it ignores scan codes that it doesn't know about. You need to declare the scan codes. At a cursory glance [this Arch Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/extra_keyboard_keys) plus the links have the information you need.

Comment: Some software can be handling these keys and preventing nested softwares (xev) identify it, try go to **keyboard keys** and look for some shortcut handling Super_L for example