# Set Ctrl+Shift as prefix in tmux

Tags: tmux

I would want to have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> as prefix in tmux (because I'm trying to switch from terminator, and the majority of my shortcuts used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>).

I tried this in my `.tmux.conf` :

```
unbind-key C-b
set-option -g prefix C-S
bind-key C-S send-prefix
```

It unbind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, but it doesn't rebind it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (actually, the second line alone has the same behavior).

Is there a way to do that, or, as these are two "special" keys, we can't bind them alone?

Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> are modifiers. These keys aren't transmitted to applications running in a terminal. Rather, when you press something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, this sends a character or a character sequence at the time you press the <kbd>A</kbd> key. See [How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work/116630#116630) for more details.

There may be some terminal emulators that can be configured to send a key sequence when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, but even that isn't a given and might depend on which order you press the two keys in, and you'd lose the ability to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+*key* shortcuts.

If your terminal emulator permits it, you could configure it to send `C-b a` when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and so on. That would allow you to use single-keychord bindings for some commands.

If you want to free the keychord <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> so that it's sent to the underlying application, pick a different prefix such as `C-\` or `C-]` or `C-^`.

Answer (score 7):

See the `man` page for the list of keys tmux recognises:

> KEY BINDINGS 
> When specifying keys, most represent themselves (for example ‘A’ to
>      ‘Z’).  Ctrl keys may be prefixed with ‘C-’ or ‘^’, and Alt (meta) with ‘M-’.  In addition, the following special key names are accepted: Up, Down,
>      Left, Right, BSpace, BTab, DC (Delete), End, Enter, Escape, F1 to F20, Home, IC (Insert), NPage/PageDown/PgDn, PPage/PageUp/PgUp, Space, and Tab.
>      Note that to bind the ‘"’ or ‘'’ keys, quotation marks are necessary.

Note that <kbd>Shift</kbd> is not included...

Comment: Those Windows-Keys would be great here ...