# tmux - Ctrl+Colon keybinding not working

Tags: bash, zsh, tmux

I am trying to use `bind-key -T root C-: command-prompt`, but it is not working.

However, `bind-key -T root M-: command-prompt` works.

How can I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>, in other words <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> as a keybinding in tmux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is not included as a default prefix key in tmux ([see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187407/set-ctrlshift-as-prefix-in-tmux)).

However, there is a function called `user-keys`. With this setting, you can define a custom escape sequence and bind that in tmux.

To test an escape sequence in Bash (as default), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> followed by the key sequence you want to test - it will then print the escape sequence.

However, for my terminal I get no valid escape sequence for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd>, which may also be the case for you.

But as an example let's take <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> on my keyboard, which produces the escape sequence `^[[1;3H` (or `\e[1;3H` in tmux).

This could then be bound in tmux using:

```
set -s user-keys[0] "\e[1;3H"
bind -T root User0 command-prompt
```

I realize the above is only partly an answer, but however outlines an alternative method which can be used, if you can generate an escape sequence from a key combination.