# bash - wrong key sequence bindings with control+alt+space

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, inputrc

I am trying to install some key sequence bindings but I have trouble.
My shell is bash, my terminal is gnome-terminal, and my system is Ubuntu 14.04 in graphic mode.
*Edit : my keyboard is french azerty with the numeric pad and ctrl,fn,super,alt.*

*Edit:* a [bash guide, readline chapter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Line-Editing)

**I want to add <kbd>contol</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>**, but this exact sequence does not work while similar other sequences work fine.
My goal is to run shell-expand-line readline but i tried upcase-word to compare.

*--Let's analyze my goal's installation effect.*

This is my `~/.inputrc` added (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>):

`"\e\C- ": shell-expand-line`

This is the new result of `bind -p` :

`"\e\C-@": shell-expand-line`

Of course I started a couple terminals, one before installation and one after every installation in order to compare thoroughly.

*--Some experiments to ensure control+alt works in place of control+meta.*

The system should emulate <kbd>Meta</kbd> with <kbd>Alt</kbd> and bash should emulate <kbd>Meta</kbd> with <kbd>Escape</kbd>, both using the byte '\033'. **I tried both <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to conclude it works fine**. I tested some ctrl+meta+letter sequences to be sure.

By the way, the individual samples of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> are simple : expanding an isolated tilde '~' (shell-expand-line) or changing case in random lowercase words (upcase-word) with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> is already binding to shell-expand-line so i just mixed the bindings with the useless <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

*--Some more intricate observations...*

I read '^@' illustrates 'NUL' character. *Why this escape?*

**I tested xev and pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> : the character reported is 'NUL' character.**

I saw alt+space usually open the window menu of gnome-terminal while alt enables menus, of course without control key.

A conflict seems to come from the system, but I am a newbie. I just read most of the bash manual (especially readline chapter) and one forum advice about xev.

*--Question*

Is there more to say or to correct?
Why the sequences are rewritten?
How can I make my <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> work with bash and gnome-terminal ?

*Edit : I found that '@' is transformed in 'NUL' because of a bitwise mask applied when escaping, but i do not see any reason why <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> gives 'NUL'.*

Comment: I have a temporary simple solution, I chose another similar key sequence : "\C-x\C-@" code to spell ctrl+x+space keys. It works, it is easy to press, x is near Alt and I do not need to hold ctrl+x.

Comment: One more workaround : **defining Meta-Space** does the trick since it is the wrong sequence sent by VTE from Ctrl+Alt+Space. But it catches the Esc+Space, what a pity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gnome-terminal (actually the underlying vte-0.34) emits the wrong sequence for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>. The bug (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=710349) was fixed in vte-0.36.

If you're not afraid of hacking a little bit and you're able to safely revert things in case of trouble, you can try to install vte-0.36 on your Ubuntu 14.04. You'll get many other fixes and improments along with this one. You might find a PPA or a package in Gnome3 staging, or compile it for yourself. Upgrading to this version of vte doesn't require touching any other software components. A complete restart of gnome-terminal is required (close all the windows).

Comment: Thank you for **linking this bugreport**, i could never find it, and it is **stronger than a workaround**. However finding package and version is a pain : my package manager (apt) do not find vte or libvte, and i found a version 2.90 in my computer. _I need to figure out how to upgrade and what upgrade before accepting the answer._

Comment: @Link-akro There's a vte3_1:0.36.3 package at Gnome3 staging (https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging/+packages), I believe installing this should work. It's actually multiple packages, upgrade whichever ones you already have installed; probably `libvte-2.90-9` and `libvte-2.90-9-common`. Should anything go wrong, open an xterm and perform an `apt-get install --reinstall libvte-2.90-9 libvte-2.90-9-common` to revert.

Comment: I learnt right now searching with apt (because I was wrong before). I now see the packages already installed : `apt search vte` reports `libvte-2.90-9/trusty,now 1:0.34.9-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]` and `libvte-2.90-common/trusty,now 1:0.34.9-1ubuntu1 all [installed]`. (I still do not understand the meaning of every data). **Anyway, local package is up to date** from what i see and `apt-get install libvte-2.90-9` or with `--reininstall`. **And I still have the key sequence bug in gnome-terminal.** Maybe something need compile, IDK.

Comment: Woops, i forgot your suggestion of 0.36.3 version. It is normal to still have the bug with the 0.34.x. Let me see gnome3 repository for 0.36 correction.

Answer (score 4):

The terminal emulator (Gnome-terminal, in your case) converts key combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (which it receives as the `Space` keysym with the `Ctrl` and meta modifiers are) into sequences of bytes. Text characters like `a` and space are sent as is; keys that don't correspond to characters are sent as control characters when there is one (e.g. byte 13 = carriage return = <kbd>Return</kbd>, byte 9 = tabulation = <kbd>Tab</kbd>) and as escape sequences beginning with byte 27 = escape if there isn't. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+character is sent as escape followed by that character (for all intents and purposes, in typical configurations nowadays, treat “Alt” and “Meta” as synonymous — I won't go into that topic in this post). See also [How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+character is sent as a control character if there is one (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> → byte 1 = ^A). There is no control-space character, but for historical reasons, the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is usually transmitted as byte 0 = ^@.

You can see what key sequence the terminal sends by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on the bash command line then the key or key combination you're interested in. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> tells bash to insert the next character, whatever it is, instead of interpreting it as a command.

It would be logical to transmit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> as the two-byte sequence 27, 0 = escape, ^@. Unfortunately for you, Gnome-terminal doesn't do this, it sends 27, 32 = escape, space instead. Key sequences sent by Gnome-terminal cannot be configured (you'd need to patch the VTE library). So if you want to be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in the terminal, you have several possibilities:

- Use a different terminal emulator. There are about 40 in Ubuntu.
- Edit the source code of the [VTE library](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libvte-dev) to make it send a different escape sequence. You may want to suggest this as an enhancement.
- Maybe use `LD_PRELOAD` to patch calls from Gnome-terminal to libvte. I haven't checked to see if it's practical, and anyway it would be cumbersome — if you care that much, use a different terminal emulator.
- Configure your window manager or an external program to change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> into <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> when a Gnome-terminal window is active. This is not easy to do without disrupting other applications in most environments.

In short, if you want to use this binding, you'll need to use a different terminal emulator, such as xterm (where escape sequences for key combinations are fully configurable).

Comment: Interesting. Easiest solution is changing terminal or sequence, but not favorite. BTW, i wonder why someone downvoted this answer.

Comment: Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (quoted-insert macro) is not what I need to study sequences. It only inserts the byte. Inserting a byte is not a clue to know what code it is. It is not easy to read something like "it tried to insert NUL". **SO i will use `hexdump` program from now on to see the exact code of any sequence.**

Comment: @Link-akro You need Ctrl+V with some sequences to prevent the terminal or the application in the terminal from interpreting the initial control character. Then you can type the sequence in `hexdump` if you want to see the hexadecimal codes.