# How can you bind ^[ or M-[ shortcut to an action in nano?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, nano

I have been trying to bind the shortcut <kbd>CTRL-[</kbd> to the unindent function, but it seems like that if you type in `bind ^[ unindent main` (<kbd>CTRL-[</kbd>) into nanorc, the text will be still formatted in red, not the usual green which tells you that the binding would work. I tried changing it to `bind M-[ unindent main` (<kbd>ALT-[</kbd>), but it still didn't work. Strangely, both <kbd>CTRL-]</kbd> and <kbd>ALT-]</kbd> works. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: perhaps not: that's the escape-character, which is easily mistaken for the beginning of cursor-movement, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Terminals send characters, not keys. (See [How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work) for more details.) But not all keys have a corresponding character. When you press a key or key chord that doesn't have a corresponding character, the terminal sends a sequence of characters that represents it, or in a few case a non-printable [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character)). These sequences always start with a particular character, which is called the *escape* character. This character is also what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> sends.

So if you could bind `^[` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>), that would break all keys that send escape sequences. For example, <kbd>Up</kbd> sends either the three characters (`^[`, `[`, `A`) or the three characters (`^[`, `O`, `A`), depending on the terminal. If you could rebind `^[` then the <kbd>Up</kbd> key would do the action of `^[` and then insert `[` and `A`.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>*char*</kbd> sends the escape character followed by *char*. So if you rebound `M-[`, you'd really be rebinding the two-character sequence (`^[`, `[`), which would break some cursor and function keys.

Nano technically allows rebinding `^[` (as of version 2.5.3) but this has no effect because when it reads `^[`, it classifies this as the start of an escape sequence (I'm simplifying a bit) and it never looks up a binding for `^[`. Nano explicitly forbids rebinding `M-[`.

[There are ways around this on *some* terminals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203418/bind-c-i-and-tab-keys-to-different-commands-in-terminal-applications-via-inputr/203521#203521), but only a few editors take advantage of them. Nano is a relatively simple editor, which primarily targets users who don't use terminals where such ways exist, and doesn't support this feature.