# Emacs running in mintty via ssh and tmux reports <end> as <select>

Tags: ssh, tmux, emacs

Currently I need to code via ssh on a remote machine. I run this from a Cygwin `mintty` and use `tmux` to keep emacs running even when I disconnect. Everything is fine, `tmux` reports `TERM=screen`, however the `<end>` key is not working. Emacs reports it as `<select>`. In the shell inside of tmux, when I do a simple `cat`, the key gets reported as `^[[4~`. The target machine is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. The end key works as expected in `zsh`, so I figure it must have to do with emacs.

When I run emacs in `tmux` locally in Cygwin, everything works fine. So I figure it's something to do with the target system. I don't want to rebind `<select>` since this seems awkward. Is it a bug in Emacs? The version is `GNU Emacs 26.3`.

I can work around this by using `C-a` and `C-e`, but would prefer a correct solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's partly application, partly configuration.  Depending on whether the terminal description is designed to imitate a VT220 or PC-whatever, the editing-keypad can have different names assigned to the keys.  At the same time, a curses application will see only the first, so duplicates are flagged (tic warnings) and generally removed.

Emacs isn't a curses application, but it's using the terminal description provided by ncurses.  So your terminal description will show one or another of end/select.  You can change the terminal description...

Further reading: [Why doesn't my keypad work?](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_keypad)

(There is a longer comment about this in xterm's [terminfo](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/terminfo-contents.html) file).

Comment: Oh, I see. So select is on the same spot / the same keycode as end on PC keyboards. Indeed mintty emulates xterm mostly. So somewhere down the pipe of nested terminal descriptors (xterm->screen) the end becomes a select key. Well, maybe I'll just add a key binding for select. That way emacs will work both normally with end as well as select.

Comment: yes, that should work well enough.

Answer (score 1):

emacs is right.  That *is* the (original) control sequence for the <kbd>select</kbd> key.  But it is most likely right via a roundabout process.

A DEC VT102 did not have an editing keypad.  That arrived with newer models.  Here is a DEC VT320 keyboard with editing keypad, at right of centre above the cursor keypad.

[image: This is a DEC VT320 keyboard]

The DEC VT220 control sequences for the editing keypad, where all this originated, are these (with the ability to encode modifiers added beginning with the DEC VT420):

- <kbd>find</kbd>:  DECFNK 1 (i.e. CSI `1` `~` or CSI `1` `;` *Mods* `~`)
- <kbd>insert</kbd>: DECFNK 1 (i.e. CSI `2` `~` or CSI `2` `;` *Mods* `~`)
- <kbd>remove</kbd> a.k.a. <kbd>delete</kbd>: DECFNK 3 (i.e. CSI `3` `~` or CSI `3` `;` *Mods* `~`) or DEL
- <kbd>select</kbd>: DECFNK 4 (i.e. CSI `4` `~` or CSI `4` `;` *Mods* `~`)
- <kbd>next screen</kbd> a.k.a. <kbd>PgDn</kbd>: DECFNK 5 (i.e. CSI `5` `~` or CSI `5` `;` *Mods* `~`)
- <kbd>prev screen</kbd> a.k.a. <kbd>PgUp</kbd>: DECFNK 6 (i.e. CSI `6` `~` or CSI `6` `;` *Mods* `~`)

The SCO XENIX Multiscreen console worked on machines with IBM Model M keyboards, and defined:

- <kbd>home</kbd>: CUP (i.e. CSI `H` theoretically extensible to CSI `1` `;` *Mods* `H`)
- <kbd>end</kbd>: CPL (i.e. CSI `F` theoretically extensible to CSI `1` `;` *Mods* `F`)

The DEC VT52x copied some things from the SCO console, including these additional control sequences.  There were two possible *arrangements* of the *editing keypad* on a DEC VT52x:

- **VT layout**, the same as the DEC VT220/320/420:

  - <kbd>find</kbd> <kbd>insert</kbd> <kbd>remove</kbd>
  - <kbd>select</kbd> <kbd>prev</kbd> <kbd>next</kbd>
- **PC layout**, the same as the IBM Model M:

  - <kbd>insert</kbd> <kbd>home</kbd> <kbd>PgUp</kbd>
  - <kbd>delete</kbd> <kbd>end</kbd> <kbd>PgDn</kbd>

The functions move to a physically different arrangement of keys, under control of a firmware setting in the terminal itself.  But the mappings from functions to their control sequences *are invariant*.

The problem is that thanks to samizdat and old wives' tales, people mixed these up in several terminal *emulators*.  The terminal emulator that is built into the Linux kernel, for example, has a bastard admixture of the two.  It uses the "PC layout", but (despite imitating SCO Multiscreen elsewhere) sends the wrong control sequences for <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd>.  It sends the <kbd>find</kbd> and <kbd>select</kbd> control sequences.

This error is now baked in.  And it has been propagated from there.

- mintty, for example, normally sends the SCO sequences for <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd>.  But it has a "VT220 mode" that causes it to behave the same way as the Linux terminal emulator, which is *not the behaviour of a VT220*, not least because *it employs the "PC" layout* which the VT220 did not have.
- rxvt uses completely wrong DECFNK codes for <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd>, overlapping two of the DECFNK assignments for the cursor keypad, DECFNK 7 and DECFNK 8.

This continually causes minor hiccoughs.

The most common hiccough is not using the correct terminal type.  The terminfo database has entries for [`putty`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty), [`mintty`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-mintty), [`linux`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-linux) et al. that define the appropriate `kend`/`khome`/`kfnd`/`kslt` capabilities with the values emitted by those types of terminal.  But if one *wrongly* uses [`vt220`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-vt220) instead, as mintty *can optionally set as the `TERM` environment variable*, what mintty sends as <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd> get understood by applications as <kbd>find</kbd> and <kbd>select</kbd>.

That's probably what is happening in your case.  A minor wrinkle is that the application doing the understanding is tmux, which is recognizing the control sequence as <kbd>select</kbd>, per the `TERM` that it has inherited being set to something like `vt220`, and then re-encoding it and passing it on.

## Further reading

- *[VT520/VT525 Video Terminal Programmer Information](http://vaxhaven.com/images/b/b5/EK-VT520-RM-A01.pdf)*.  EK-VT520-RM.  July 1994.  Digital.
- [`keyboard`](https://archive.org/stream/SCOUnixDocumentation/SCO_Unix_System_Administrators_Reference_v324d#page/n683/mode/2up).  "Hardware Dependent".  *SCO Unix System Administrators Reference*.  1993-02-01.  The Santa Cruz Operation.  archive.org.
- https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9268/1932
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479274/5132