# Question about behavior of control key shortcuts

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, escape-characters

I am confused about how `Ctrl-key` combinations work in terminal. In bash man page, there are various combinations such as:

- `C-e` - go to end of the line
- `C-f` - go one character forward

etc.

But then there are some *undocumented* shortcuts such as:

- `C-j` (OR `C-m`) for return key.
- `C-h` for backspace
- `C-i` for tab
  etc.

Are these shortcuts just forgotten to be documented? Or, because

- `C-j` is `LF`
- `C-m` is `CR`
- `C-i` is `Tab`

in ASCII, is this somehow a "default" behavior? In other words, is the behavior for `C-j`, `C-m` and `C-i` not implemented *by* bash but by something else?

Another question is, when I press `C-v` and left arrow key, `^[[D` appears on screen. I.e, `ESC-[-d`. But when I press `ESC-[-d`, the cursor does not move left. What is the reason for this?

### EDIT:

Initially, I have thought that when I press `C-j`, the keyboard directly sends `00001010` to kernel. But then I decided that this is not the case, because using programs such as `xev` or `evtest`, I have observed that key presses to `Control` and `j` appear as different events. So when I press `C-j`, the keyboard does not send `00001010`, but probably multiple bytes. Then where the conversion of these multiple bytes to `00001010` is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of `C-m`, `C-i`, etc. is implemented by bash, but the fact that they're the same thing as <kbd>Return</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, etc. is due to the behavior of the terminal. All terminals behave like this because all terminals have always behaved like this and it's what applications expect. The interface between a terminal and an application is based on characters (in fact, bytes), not on keys, so keys that don't send printable characters and key combinations have to be encoded somehow. See [How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work) for more on this topic. See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal

`TAB` is the tab character in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), and that's the same thing as the Ctrl+I character in ASCII. Likewise for the other keys. Terminals send that character both when the user presses <kbd>Tab</kbd> and when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. Ditto for `RET` (CR) and `C-m`, for `LFD` and `C-j` (which most keyboards don't have), and for `ESC` and `C-[`. There's also <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> which sends either `C-h` or `C-?`, that's an issue of its own.

The configuration of the terminal (`stty` settings) can additionally come into play, and this affects some of bash's settings (e.g. after `stty erase @`, bash will treat pressing `@` as BackSpace), but not `C-m` and `C-j` to submit the current line.

`^[[D` is <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>, but with a capital `D`. If you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>, bash sees the <kbd>Left</kbd> key, due to the declaration of cursor key escape sequences in the [termcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) or [terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) database. There's no default binding for <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> (it isn't an escape sequence that common terminals send).

Comment: I was going to leave a comment but made an edit to make it more clear :-)

Comment: @Utku My first link should answer your added question.

Comment: I'd also point to Eric S. Raymond's [Things Every Hacker Once Knew](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/things-every-hacker-once-knew/) for an explanation of the historical, technical reasons that Ctrl+... combinations work the way they do.

Answer (score 0):

Two questions, two points:

- control/<kbd>J</kbd>, control/<kbd>M</kbd> and control/<kbd>I</kbd> are common ASCII controls which most programs assume.  `bash` simply makes it easy to rebind those in readline.
- most programs which accept special keys such as left-arrow provide a way to recognize the escape key *distinguished* from those special keys by *timing*.  You probably cannot type fast enough to enter the characters (except for special cases such as emacs, which does *not* pay attention to timing).

  Since you don't type that fast, the program sees the separate characters, which won't move the cursor.  The separate characters *may* do something interesting.

Regardless of that (noting a comment about a typo which I overlooked in the question), <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> is a standard control sequence, which if sent to a terminal would move the cursor to the top line of the screen:

```
CSI Pm d  Line Position Absolute  [row] (default = [1,column]) (VPA).
```

Since [xterm implements this](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), anything which pretends to be just like xterm will do the same, of course. [Linux console](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-linux-basic) does that, too. However, `bash` generally doesn't echo control sequences: the behavior you observe would be whatever `bash` does with escapes which it doesn't recognize.

Regarding form-feeds (a comment assumes they are part of the question): bash's use of form-feed (for *input*) to clear the screen [confuses some people](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_form_feed) (including PuTTY's developers) into supposing that terminals should interpret a form-feed.  That feature actually comes from line-printers and originally was rarely found in terminals, even the printing variety.  For some related discussion, see my notes on a [*repaginator*](http://invisible-island.net/personal/oldprogs.html#repaginator) and [followups](http://invisible-island.net/personal/oldprogs.html#dis) to reuse the feature.

Comment: What do you mean by `most programs assume`? I mean, combinations like `C-f` are definetely due to Readline (because it is in documentation) but are combinations like `C-j` and `C-i` due to Readline as well?

Comment: ASCII form-feed predates `bash` (as well as most of the readers of this site).