# Why Alt+Backspace is bound to delete-word in Debian's gnome-terminal?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, history

I am used to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> in Ubuntu and OS X. 
I want to understand this because it helps me how the system is designed and built. Still, you have the emacs keybindings like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, ... in Terminal. 
However, internet browsers still use persistently <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> for the task. 
I would like to maintain some sort of consistency for the basics. 
Other differences in Debian in comparison to Ubuntu

- moving around tabs in Terminal - have not found any keybinding for the task; In Ubuntu, I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, ...

OS: Debian 8.5
Window manager: Gnome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are key bindings of the shell ([bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)), not of the terminal. See [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con) Nonetheless, the terminal is involved in translating keychords into escape sequences. See [How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work)

Bash uses Emacs key bindings (unless you switch to vi mode). In Emacs, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd> (`M-backspace`) deletes the previous word. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd> (`C-backspace`) was traditionally not bound, though modern versions also bind it to the command to delete the previous word.

The escape sequence for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>*key*</kbd> is the escape character followed by the character for <kbd>*key*</kbd>, when <kbd>*key*</kbd> sends a single character. There's no standard escape sequence for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd>, and it's usually not distinguishable from other keys. This is why terminal applications (including classic Emacs) tend not to have bindings for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd>. In gnome-terminal, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd> sends the same characte as <kbd>BackSpace</kbd>, so it isn't possible to have a separate binding for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd>.

Gnome-terminal's keychord-to-escape-sequence translations are not configurable. If you want to use different translations, use a configurable terminal emulator such as rxvt or xterm.