# What is the difference between `/dev/input/event*` and `/dev/input/mouse*` according to mouses?

Tags: devices, mouse

Suppose my mouse is associated to `/dev/.../event1` and `/dev/.../mouse1`.

I was reading the byte streams of those files, and I noticed that `event1` gives much more information than `mouse1`, which sometimes returns the same thing when doing different actions.

What is the real input of the mouse? Im trying to write a mouse driver by myself so I need this information.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451618/how-do-you-read-the-mouse-button-state-from-dev-input-mice.

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340430/dev-input-what-exactly-is-this & this is the kernel docs on it - https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/input/input.html.

Comment: This AU Q&A looks like it covers everything you're looking for - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043832/difference-between-dev-input-mouse0-and-dev-input-mice.

Comment: The Linux subsystem userspace API - https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/input_uapi.html.