# Line editing (readline?) with virtual keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, readline, line-editor, keyboard-event

I want to bind terminal behavior to hotkeys without having to define escape sequences.

I understand readline binds to characters instead of actual key presses. Can it also bind to the lower level virtual keys? e.g. so I can use `CTRL`+`LEFT_ARROW` instead of whatever ascii escape sequence (`^[^[D`) my current terminal uses.

How can I achieve this behavior (doesn't have to be readline). I don't use X, just the Linux console and terminal text editors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

readline can't do that.  Some applications can open a connection to the X server and detect X events (such as `xev`), but the readline library isn't one of those applications.

Call it a *technical limitation*.  readline uses system interfaces (mostly [POSIX termios](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11)) which can only read the *characters* sent by the terminal, and has no access to their internal state.

Comment: I don't have a window server. Is this limitation by design or would it have technical reasons?

Comment: @jiggunjer Yes, there's a technical reason: terminal applications receive characters as input, not keys. See [“Text mode application, running in a terminal” — “Input”](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work/116630#116630). If you want to have access to key events, use X11.

Comment: @Gilles I am skeptical of the advice to install a graphics stack just to change the character-centric behavior of a terminal. While *terminal applications* such as bash receive characters, the *terminal itself* also receives "keys" from the keyboard. Instead of converting certain keys to characters and passing them on to the application (or ignoring them), I want to map terminal behavior/attribute modifiers to certain keys. Maybe there is a userland alternative to the `TERM=linux` console that does this.

Comment: @jiggunjer A shell or text editor running in a terminal is an application. There is a mechanism to bypass the terminal interface and access the underlying hardware driver directly (svgalib) but I doubt that you'll find a shell or text editor that supports it, because everybody has moved to X since about 20 years agao.