# Text insertion bindings in zsh

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, rxvt

In zsh, how can I bind (say) `c-<cr>` to insert `&>/dev/null &<cr>` at point?

I use urxvt.

Comment: What terminal emulator do you use?

Comment: @Gilles, urxvt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two steps: you need to get your terminal emulator to emit a distinct escape sequence for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>, and you need to tell zsh what to do when that escape sequence is typed.

An application in a terminal receives sequences of bytes, most of which either form printable characters or are [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character). Most function keys and keychords need to be encoded as escape sequences consisting of the escape character followed by a few characters that encode which keychord was pressed. See [How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work) for more background. There's no standard escape sequence for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>, and most terminals, including (U)rxvt, simply send a CR character, just like for a plain <kbd>Return</kbd>. So you need to tell Urxvt to send a different escape sequence. In your X resources file (`~/.Xresources` — load it with `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`), add

```
URxvt.keysym.C-Return: \033[27;5;13~
```

In zsh, to bind custom code to a key, write that code in a function and declare that function as a zle widget with [`zle -N`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-zle). Inside your [user-defined widget](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#User_002dDefined-Widgets), the variable [`BUFFER`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-BUFFER) contains the content of the line being edited, and [`CURSOR`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-CURSOR) contains the cursor position. To insert text around the cursor, there are also more convenient variables: you can append text to [`LBUFFER`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-LBUFFER) to insert it before the cursor, or prepend text to [`RBUFFER`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-RBUFFER) to insert it after the cursor.

I think what you want to do is add text at the end of the line and run the current command. Running the current command is not done by inserting a CR character, that would just insert a CR in the command. Call the widget [`accept-line`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-accept_002dline) (which is bound to CR by default) to run the command.

```
accept-line-run-in-background-with-output-hidden () {
  BUFFER+=" &>/dev/null &"
  zle accept-line
}
zle -N accept-line-run-in-background-with-output-hidden
bindkey $'\033[27;5;13~' accept-line-run-in-background-with-output-hidden
```