# Why does Super-F1 display "::1 localhost"?

Tags: bash, konsole

Why does pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> cause the terminal to output the following (including "s1") on the following prompt?

```
~ $ 
::1        localhost  
~ $ s1
```

Note: The value of `$?` seems to be preserved, so I don't believe it's executing a command.

Environment:  Gentoo Linux, Gnome 3.20.0, Konsole 16.08.3-r1

Comment: This looks like a list of users (X display, host). What output does the command `w` produce on your system?. What happens if you first type `'` (apostrophe), and then `Super` + `F1`?

Comment: Terminals translate function keys to escape sequences. See [How do keyboard input and text output work?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work) for some background. Run `cat` and press Super+F1, what gets inserted?