# Echoed escape sequences doesn't interpreted in Linux tty

Tags: linux, tty, terminal-emulator, stty

#### Prerequisites

The Linux virtual terminal (tty) is an emulation of **VT102** - [Virtual terminal subsystem source.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/tty/vt/vt.c?id=HEAD)

The real **VT100** (nearly the same as **VT102**) has the following behavior (I suppose):

- In the **LINE** mode all typed characters are first transmitted to the computer and then, returned to the terminal. Nothing is displayed on the terminal screen before returning from the host.
- The escape sequences are no exception - they are parsed and executed only after returning from the host. That is, if I want to change the font color to red, I should type `ESC[0;31m`, this sequence goes to the computer, echoed back, **VT102** receive this, parse and apply. There is no other way to change the terminal font color (in the **LINE** mode). I am not sure if the **VT102** had different font colors though, but that is an example.

**Picture from manual:**

[image]

**Excerpt from manual:**

> **LINE/LOCAL**
>
> The LINE/LOCAL feature allows the operator to easily place the terminal in either an ON-LINE or a LOCAL (off-line) condition. When the terminal is on-line (ON-LINE indicator is lit) all characters typed on the keyboard are sent directly to the computer and messages from the computer are displayed on the screen. In the LOCAL condition (LOCAL indicator is lit), the terminal is electrically disconnected from the computer; messages are not sent to or received from the computer; and characters typed on the keyboard are echoed on the screen directly.

**Source: VT100 series video terminal technical manual, third Edition, July 1982.**

---

#### The question

Why does the Linux `tty` behave in a different way?

I put the `bash` into the sleep mode, so it doesn't interfere, then type <kbd>Esc</kbd>`[0;31m` and get just plain text, the color haven't changed - so, escape sequence has no effect.

[image]

I were ask the similar question couple of years ago - [Why i can't send escape sequences from keyboard, but can do it from another tty?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/369845/109397), but now I got the knowledge about **VT102** Linux subsystem and want to understand why it works this way - not identically to the real hardware terminal in this aspect.

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as "sleep mode".  There is the `sleep` utility that just sleeps. While that utility is running, just like when any other utility is running in the foreground, the input that you type is buffered.  If the utility reads its standard input stream, it would see what you typed, otherwise the shell would get it when the utility terminates.  Until _something_ reads what you have typed, it can not be interpreted as a colour-changing escape sequence.

Comment: @Kusalananda I agree. It is just abstract phrase, pointing to the fact that `bash` is not interfere. "I put the bash into the sleep mode, so it doesn't interfere" - how it can be rephrased to better, while saving sense and clarity? "Disable `bash`" - also isn't right.

Comment: @Kusalananda "I use the `sleep` program to stop the `bash` from interfering" - good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, this question was asked on [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com), but the community found it more suitable for this site. But I got an answer in the comment section, so copy it here:

> The Linux virtual console emulates a (sort of) VT102 terminal in
>   ON-LINE mode connected to a Linux (serial) tty device. The Linux tty
>   driver doesn't normally echo back the escape control character, and
>   instead echos **^[**. If you don't want the tty driver to do this, then
>   use **stty -ctlecho**. Also real VT102 terminals don't support colour, it
>   works with the Linux virtual console anyways because its not really
>   VT102 compatible.

I have tried the `stty -ctlecho` and it works almost as expected - only one subquestion - is the real **VT102** also wasn't displaying characters after person press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and start type escape sequence, so the person were type it in the blind manner?

Answer (score 1):

Long question, reduced to

> Why the Linux tty behaves in different way?

Actually it's not the ***tty***, but the application (such as your ***shell***) which controls what and how characters are echoed.  You can use the *`stty`* application to change the terminal mode temporarily (some shells will change it back), e.g.,

```
stty -cooked
```

(making it "raw", telling the terminal driver to not interfere).

Comment: But I disabled `bash` by `sleep 10m` command, so it is not interfering. Anyway the `stty` is the right approach. I added answer by myself.

Comment: `stty -cooked` works too, but `stty -ctlecho` more convenient, because it is disabling only the unneeded part. More fine grained way.

Comment: Well, it IS the tty controlling the echo behavior, it's part of the tty's state. But application can change the state

Comment: The ***tty driver*** is a program, which is not the same thing as the ***tty***.

Answer (score 0):

> ...type it in the blind manner

We are getting close, I think. You did quite a nice documentation. Just the demo is missing! In your old Q [send-escape-sequences-from-keyboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369845/why-i-cant-send-escape-sequences-from-keyboard-but-can-do-it-from-another-tty) you only show what does NOT work! And both the titles??? Can you not make that clearer? And a screenshot like mine (in my answer to above linked Q)

Nobody was meant to enter one of these *long* sequences *blindly*. On a nicely setup VTxxx you would have special keys and special bindings, maybe shell functions, where the CSs are stored. On a system like that, everything is coordinated. Linux and xterm are emulating it because it's the only thing close to a standard.

But yes, the Escape key does mean: the next key is not input, but a command. So somebody has to start hold back the bytes and check for a predefined sequence.

But if the sequence gets impossible, the shell falls out of Escape mode and starts echoing again. Press Escape, [, then 1,1,1...and the bracket and two "1" get lost.

Try to enter `[32m` after an Escape...the "m" reappears again, which means, the shell gave up on that sequence. The useless ^[[32 is lost, I should say, somewhere.

Knock out bash/readline, put tty out of work: you will be left with just a kid's toy where you can place colored letters (bold, underlined, blinking, invisible) all over your screen.

I don't understand your Q. An "**echoed** Escape sequence" is for me one that did not make it to the target and really got reflected. Like when I try to use Left Arrow at the read prompt (after typing abc):

```
$  read
abc^[[D
```

At the normal prompt, when I type "abc", then Escape, then blindly "[D" the cursor moves left. The Arrow key is just an easier way to generate that.

To get your sequences through, use `echo -e '\e...'` or `echo '^[...'` (with ctrl-V). That way the shell sends the escape and does not interpret (cook?) it.

And with `stty -echoctl` and `sleep 1000` you have even discovered a way to throw a CS into tty's face directly. Sorry: tty's *driver's* face.

[here I need an even better change-color-while-bash-is-sleeping-and-tty-offguard jpeg...]