# What is the difference between shell builtins and shell keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: bash, shell, keyboard-shortcuts, shell-builtin, terminology

What is the difference between shell builtins (like `cd` or `echo`) and shell keyboard shortcuts (like `ctrl+u` or `ctrl+l`)?

Both seems to me "builtins", what is the major difference by means of system architecture?

I personally use Bash but I believe this question is relevant for many other `sh` shells.

Comment: Background reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116630/117549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most builtins change the status / behaviour of the shell ("permanently"). `echo` and `printf` are exceptions.

`^U` and `^L` are key bindings. They just handle the input line editing. You could do the same without these functions. They just save time. After executing a command it does not make a difference whether a key binding function was used earlier.

The maybe most obvious difference is that key bindings are not a command which you can run from the command line. You need a builtin (`bind`) to configure them (shell "state change").

Comment: @Arcticooling See my edit

Comment: Hmm thanks. I thumbed up. Just one more last thing - The first passage was a bit unclear to me `(change the behavior of the shell ("permanently")`. Given all is changeable, generally, so I didn't quite understand what you meant right there.

Comment: @Arcticooling E.g. `shopt -s extglob nullglob globstar failglob` changes the way the shell does globbing. This change is in effect until it is changed again with `shopt`.