# What part of the Linux system is responsible for the effects of Ctrl+Shift+U?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, unicode

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> on a Linux based system (not sure about UNIX) in any textbox you get a small underscored *u*. You can then proceed to enter hexadecimal numbers and confirm them with enter. The result you'll get is the Unicode character with the respective hexadecimal number.

For example typing in u6a4c and pressing enter will result in 橌 being written to the text box.

I used a lot of Linux based OSes and everyone of them had this functionality so I wanted to know, does any Linux system come with this and what part of a Linux system is responsible for this feature?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/117549 https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/116629/117549

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so much a *Linux* thing so much as it is a *desktop environment* thing.  You may observe, for example, that if you were to `ssh` into your host from elsewhere, or to log into a TTY rather than the GUI, that your keyboard will no longer work as you describe as your keyboard input is not being parsed by your GUI any longer.

Comment: Ever tried this with TTY that has support for UTF and Asian locales ?

Comment: That should be a proper question, not an answer comment.