# Can emacs running under urxvt recognize the Hyper modifier key?

Tags: emacs, rxvt, keyboard-event

Can emacs running under urxvt be made to recognize <kbd>Hyper</kbd>?  From what I can tell, it doesn't distinguish <kbd>hyper</kbd>+<kbd>*something*</kbd> from just plain unmodified <kbd>*something*</kbd>.  urxvt itself does recognize the modifier, I am told.  But I cannot work out whether emacs in turn can, and if so how to configure this.

Comment: [Source code](https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/blob/master/src/init.C#L1242) says it recognizes it - that's a place to start...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may not even need to play with `xmodmap`, nor modifiers, just bind them in your `~/.Xdefaults` like this:

```
URxvt.keysym.XF86AudioPlay: string:\030@m
URxvt.keysym.Menu: string:\030@s
URxvt.keysym.Muhenkan: string:\030@h
```

## How it works

To get a good explanation on how key events are handled, see [How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work) first.

TL;DR: Let's take "C-a" as an example, emacs won't receive "Ctrl down, a down, a up, ctrl up", urxvt does, and convert it to `\1` (yes, ctrl- sequences  are short, `C-a` maps to `\1`, `C-b` maps to `\2`, `C-c` maps to `\3` and so on).

Here my modification happen very late in the process, when urxvt send the escape sequences. I'm asking urxvt to send `\030@m` to emacs, which is `C-x @ m` (look at man ascii, 030 on the left column is conveniently aligned with X on the right column). `C-x @ m` adds the meta modifier, `C-x @ s` adds the super modifier, and `C-x @ h` adds the hyper modifier (see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html).

Happen on my keyboard I have XF86AudioPlay, Menu, and Muhenkan keys conveniently placed near to my Ctrl key, so I bound meta, super, and hyper to them.

There may be a better solution, we'd have to learn how emacs expects to receive meta and hyper escape sequences, to send directly the right one instead of using the `C-x @ s` workaround, intended to be used when one does *not* have said keys.