# Issue All-In-One Inspiron 2310 Monitor Volume Keys

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, monitors, audio-volume

At the side panel from my all in one monitor, there are 2 keys for raising and lowering volume (see picture).

After installing Ubuntu 16.04.03, both keys working proper but after the first system update to the kernel 4.13.0-36 (also kernel 4.15.0-29 and Ubuntu 18.04) only the upper button for raising volumen works, the other stop working. I get no output with xev and showkey command when I use the "volume -"button.

With a fresh install without any updates I tried "showkey -s" and it says, the keycode for lowering volume is: 0xe0 0x2e 0xe0 0xae and for raising volume is: 0xe0 0x30 0xe0 0xb0

Related to this issue: [How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work)
I think it is on the kernel versions. Is it possible to compare both kernels to see what is missing?

[image]

Summarized:
Both hardware volume keys (DELL InspironOne 2310) on side Panel working with an old kernel but after updating kernel/ MATE 18.04. the button for lowering volume is dead and didn't showing off a keycode.