# Is there a way I can tab between screens without pressing ctrl-a tab every time?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen, alias, stty

Essentially I just want to press <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd>, not <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> then <kbd>Tab</kbd>.  I don't believe this can be accomplished with an alias, but have read some stuff about maybe using `stty`? But I've never used `stty` and not sure how this would be done.

Comment: Use [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/)+[xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/).

Comment: What screens are you referring to here? You have tagged this with `gnu-screen`.  Do you mean switching between GNU `screen` windows in a terminal?

Comment: Are you running GNU `screen` in an X11 environment like Gnome or KDE or similar desktop manager?

Comment: How are you access the Unix machine?  Is it from X-windows, or SSH'd in from from an MS-Windows machine (eg with `putty`) or some other method?

Comment: I have Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, running xterm-256Color.  I usually just open two windows to have 2 different environments to work in, but have found "screen" command which has kind of what i'm looking for 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614785/bash-how-to-use-screen-to-have-a-term-session-used-at-home-after-work

Although something that I dont like about this is that you cant scroll up the different sessions, it only allows you to scroll up both at the same time.  What do you guys use to partition your terminals in half?

Comment: On a side note, i also have linux up on my raspberry pi A+, and will be wanting to do something similar with it as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but only with the cooperation of your terminal emulator. Terminal emulators send escape sequences (or in a few cases a single control character) to indicate the press of a function key. See the “terminal — input” section of [How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work) for more details. You need to configure your terminal to send a unique escape sequence for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Some terminals send the Tab character for both plain <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, so that applications can't distinguish between them. To see what your terminal sends, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. If you see a few spaces, that's bad and you need to reconfigure your terminal, if possible. How to do that depends entirely on the terminal software. If you see something like `^[O5` (escape, `O`, `5`), that's fine.

Assuming that your terminal sends a unique escape sequence for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, you can tell Screen what to do with it with the command [`bindkey`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Bindkey). (It's `bind` for bindings that start with the “Screen key” <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and `bindkey` for other key bindings). For example, with the control sequence above, put the following line in your `.screenrc`:

```
bindkey ^[O5 next
```

Comment: It does give me a space when pressing Ctrl + V then Ctrl + Tab.  But i'm finding out that "screen" is a command i'm not liking, and am searching for something else to help me partition one terminal in half into two.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xterm, add this to your **~/.Xresources** file:

```
*vt100.translations: #override \n\
        Ctrl ~Shift <Key>Tab: string(0x1b) string("[27;5;9~") \n \
        Ctrl Shift <Key>Tab: string(0x1b) string("[27;6;9~") \n
```

This goes in your screenrc configuration file:

```
bindkey "^[[27;5;9~" focus
```

Make sure to log out of your X session.

Comment: `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` can be used to merge in the changes to the existing session so the next `xterm` will pick up the changes.

Answer (score -1):

Use [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/)+[xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/).
Append to `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"xdotool key ctrl+a Tab"
    release+Control + Tab
```

Comment: This is assuming that the user runs some sort of desktop environment (or at least X11), right? This is very likely, but not universal (I don't, for example).

Comment: This would make it impossible to use Ctrl+Tab normally in other applications.