# How is ctrl + / working as undo in Zsh 5.7.1 on Debian 10.0?

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Debian 10.0 system. It has zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu). In ZSH prompt, I type

```
foo bar baz
```

Then I type <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>backspace</kbd> two times. The words `baz` and `bar` get deleted and only `foo` remains.

Then I type <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> two times to undo the deletions. The words `baz` and `bar` reappear.

How is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> working as the undo command? I don't see it defined anywhere?

```
$ echo / | grep -E "/|undo"  # just testing my regex
/
$ bindkey -l
.safe
command
emacs
isearch
main
vicmd
viins
viopp
visual
$ bindkey -M .safe | grep -E "/|undo"
$ bindkey -M command | grep -E "/|undo"
$ bindkey -M emacs | grep -E "/|undo" 
"^X^U" undo
"^Xu" undo
"^_" undo
```

I also have a macOS Catalina 10.15.7 with zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0) and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> does not do anything there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) for <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, so there's no natural choice of character or character sequence that the terminal can send. Many terminals send `^_`, i.e. the same character as <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>. This includes xterm, rxvt, konsole and all terminals based on the vte library (Gnome Terminal, Mate Terminal, lxterminal, Terminator, …), but not macOS's built-in Terminal application.

You can see what your terminal sends by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> means “insert the next character literally” (even if it would be otherwise interpreted as a command).

(For the role of the terminal, see [How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work/116630#116630))

`^_` is the shortcut for undo in Emacs and applications with Emacs-inspired keyboard shortcuts.