# How is Ctrl + / working as undo in Bash 5.0.3 on Debian 10.0?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Debian 10.0 system. It has GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). In Bash prompt, I type

```
foo bar baz
```

Then I type <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>backspace</kbd> two times. The words `baz` and `bar` get deleted and only `foo` remains.

Then I type <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> two times to undo the deletions. The words `baz` and `bar` reappear.

How is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> working as the undo command? I don't see it defined anywhere?

```
$ echo / | grep -E "/|undo"  # just testing my regex
/
$ bind -p | grep -E '/|undo'
"\e/": complete-filename
"\C-x/": possible-filename-completions
"/": self-insert
"\C-x\C-u": undo
"\C-_": undo
```

Comment: Hit Ctrl+v, Ctrl+/ . Do you get `^_`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, I do.

Comment: So `"\C-_": undo` applies. Although I cannot tell why Ctrl+/ keystroke generates Ctrl+_, therefore it's only a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I think this question can be closed as a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/629365/131209 . The answer there for Zsh seems to explain the behavior for Bash too.